# Youtube API v3 - manage channels owned by someone else

Tags: youtube-api

A Youtube channel can be managed by multiple users that are "Administrators" of the channel.

Does the API allow us to act on those channels? The use case:

- list "unlisted" playlists (actually only "public" playlists are returned...) ;
- upload "unlisted" videos on that channel ;
- add video to a playlist retrieved before ;

We noticed the existence of "onBehalfOfContentOwner" and the associated "partner" scope. Our tests were not successfull using it. If that is a solution, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Regards.